# Is it possible to retrieve user from thread context in Presto with a custom credential provider for S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, presto, trino

For Presto to access data on S3, I need to be able to assume different roles for different users (ex Bob -> role1 and Brenda -> role2). I know EMRFS provides this functionality however we are moving Presto off of EMR so we can no longer use EMRFS to do this delegation.

Presto allows you to write your own [S3 credential provider](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#custom-s3-credentials-provider) for the native S3 file system, however it only takes two arguments a `java.net.Uri` and a Hadoop `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` as the constructors.

I've written a custom credential provider which shows all the properties of the `Configuration` object as well as the `Uri` and neither contains any information pertaining to the user.

Is it possible to retrieve the user information from the provider without modifying the source code of Presto? I see that there was a PR submitted a while back (https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/2640 see last comment) but closed out due to the addition of the custom credential provider. The documentation above hints that you could assume different IAM roles for different users but I have yet to find how the context is passed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible today. It's complicated due to the lifecycle of the `PrestoS3FileSystem`, and because S3 accesses are lazy and happen in random places where the user context is not available. I have some ideas on how to allow this. Another potential approach is the recently added credential passthrough which is supported for GCP.

Please file an issue at https://github.com/prestosql/presto and we can determine the best way to support this use case. We can also discuss this on our Slack: https://prestosql.io/community.html